# how to move data from one database (main serevr (sql)) to another in android database (local (sqlite))

Tags: android

I need to move data from one database to another , both databases are of same schema, only thing one database is will be in server and one will be in application (local sqlite database)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are heaps of good tutorials for achieving the syncing and communication between an Android App and a server (via web service) around:

[first](http://www.androidhive.info/2012/05/how-to-connect-android-with-php-mysql/)

[second](http://www.helloandroid.com/tutorials/connecting-mysql-database)

[third](http://mobinis.blogspot.com.au/2012/11/android-tutorial-for-remote-mysql-data.html)

Just search for "android php (my)sql" or maybe "android jsp (my)sql" if you go tomcat or some other java server.

Answer (score 0):

One of the most promising way is to create an app to sync database over server to local database. It'll take more time but would be working. For this you need to create a web service.

Comment: no the actual thing is to reduce latency while fetching data from actual server i'm planning to create local app server , in which every once in month ill feed the data from actual server to local server so when the app requires data it will fetch from local db , but i don't know how to pass full table values from server db to local db in onclick function.

Comment: @Khushi What do you mean "local app server"?

Comment: @d'alar'cop i mean sqlite database, application database.

Comment: @Khushi I'm not sure that's really a server - i.e. it cannot accept requests externally, right? - what's wrong with the tutorials provided above?

Comment: that tutorials i know better, the stuff im looking is like, think there is one database in cloud (amazon) in that one database i just have one table , all the times if my android application requests that table it might take long time to download the data so what i thought of doing is same like cloud database ill create one database in android application , then in my application ill click refresh button that time the data from the cloud database need to stored into database which i created in application , how to achieve this my question.

Comment: @Khushi You will need to have a web service (e.g. php or jsp) running over your "cloud" database. Then use the info in the tutorials to pull what you want using a http request to that web service - then save it to the SQLite database on command - it's all in the tutorials.

Comment: @Khushi May I trouble you to tick up my "tutorial-based" answer? And don't be afraid to tick it up either!! All the best mate.